# Java - multirow array

Tags: java

Here is my situation: a company has x number of employees and x number of machines. 
When someone is sick, the program have to give the best possible solution of people on the machines. But the employees can't work on every machine. I need a code for making little groups of possible solutions.

this is a static example
private int[][] arrayCompetenties={{0,0,1,0,1},{1,0,1,0,1},{1,1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,1}};
=> row is for the people and columns are for machines

```
    m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  m7
p1  1               1       
p2      1   1   1   1       
p3          1       1       1
p4      1       1       1   
p5  1       1       1       1
p6              1   1   1   1
p7  1       1   1   1   1   1
```

my question => with what code do i connect all the people to machine in groups (all the posibilities)

like:

p1 -> m1 , p2->m2 , p3 -> m3 , p4->m4 , p5 -> m5 , p6->m6

p1 -> m1 , p2->m3 , p3 -> m3 , p4->m4 , p5 -> m5 , p6->m6

p1 -> m1 , p2->m4 , p3 -> m5 , p4->m4 , p5 -> m5 , p6->m6

p1 -> m1 , p2->m5 , p3 -> m3 , p4->m4 , p5 -> m5 , p6->m6

p1 -> m1 , p2->m2 , p3 -> m3 , p4->m4 , p5 -> m5 , p6->m6

....

i need a loop buth how? =D

thanks!

Comment: here is the right table:

   m1   m2   m3   m4   m5   m6   m7 

p1 1    0    0    0    1    0    0
p2 0    1    1    1    1    0    0
p3 0    0    1    0    1    0    1
p4 0    1    0    1    0    1    0
p5 1    0    1    0    1    0    1
p6 0    0    0    1    1    1    1
p7 1    0    1    1    1    1    1

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to to generate all [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of machines and users. Take a look at that link, especially on the algorithms used to generate permutations.

Keep in mind that the number of permutations for n machines/users is n! (n factorial, or n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 2 * 1), which grows extremely quickly -- for 10 users, 3.6 million possibilities, and for a company of 50 people, you're looking at 3.0 * 10^64 different combinations, which wouldn't fit on all the world's computers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is with recursion.  The following is very pseudocode because the data structures aren't trivial, but you get the idea:

```
printMachineAssignments(person, assignedMachines)
    for every machine in person's competencies that's not in assignedMachines
        assign person to machine
        add machine to assignedMachines
        if no more people
            print assignments to the screen
        else
            printMachineAssignments(person + 1, assignedMachines)
```